# Arduino and Nextion won't communicate

Tags: arduino, serial-communication, nextion

I am developing a project using Arduino Uno with DTH Sensor AM2302 and Nextion 4024T032 for display. But after running the program I can't seem to find whats wrong with code. After following steps and process, I come to face an error like this, the Serial Monitor prompts the message  " ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮bkcmd=1⸮⸮⸮page 0⸮⸮⸮ ". I don't know what it means or even what caused the error but due to this the adruino can't communicate with the nextion display.

I know it may seem a simple problem and I guess I just missed a crucial part for setting both of the device. But I really don't know where to start looking now. Wish you could all give me some advice or insights. Thanks.

Regarding on my code I noticed that the  error is the result of nexInit() function in the void setup() . When I remove it the error disappears but leaving the arduino and nextion no communication whatsoever.

```
#include "Nextion.h"
#include "DHT.h"

NexText stat_text = NexText(0,1,"t0");

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  nexInit(); 
}

void loop(void){

 stat_text.setText ("Server Condition: Normal");

}
```

I expect the output would be visible in the display which correspond to the object name of GUI in the nextion display.

I have attached the Serial Monitor Error Output. [Serial Monitor Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4jhh.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about your arduino code and you are using new library for nextion, you should delete new library and install old library. new library for nextion has problems.